# Convert String Variable to URI using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia, stardog

Using a string as an URI works using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?db_uri ?uri ?db_uri_var ?prop ?val

{
BIND(URI("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Delta_Air_Lines") as ?db_uri)
      
      SERVICE <http://DBpedia.org/sparql>
{
?db_uri ?prop ?val .
}
}
```

However, as the value for the string comes "from somewhere else", I would need to use a variable inside the URI-call. This seems not to work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?db_uri ?uri ?db_uri_var ?prop ?val

{
BIND("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Delta_Air_Lines" as ?uri)
BIND(URI(?uri) as ?db_uri)
      
      SERVICE <http://DBpedia.org/sparql>
{
?db_uri ?prop ?val .
}
}
```

Comment: which SPARQL engine do you use? sounds like the `db_uri` isn't passed into the SERVICE clause which might just be some inefficiency of the query optimizer

Comment: I am using Stardog 7.7.1

Comment: Have you tried putting the BIND (I'd probably use a VALUES instead) *inside* the SERVICE block?  E.g., something like `...  SERVICE <http://DBpedia.org/sparql> { VALUES (?db_uri) { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Delta_Air_Lines> } ?db_uri ?prop ?val } ...` ?

Comment: That said, if you're using a fixed value like that, do you really need to bind it to a variable at all?  You can just do `... SERVICE <...> { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Delta_Air_Lines> ?prop ?val } ...` after all.

Comment: Moving the BIND did not do the trick either; I have used the workaround to change the type from string to URI within the DB; however, I keep investigating solving the original problem; and yes, unfortunately the values come from another query, hence I have to use a variable

Comment: putting the `BIND` part inside the `SERVICE` clause has to work in my point of view because the whole graph pattern is simply evaluated remotely on the DBpedia (backed by Virtuoso) endpoint

Comment: what can fail is indeed to inline previously bound data because this is also the issue with the rather unspecified evaluation of `SERVICE` clauses in combination with inline data (`VALUES` and `BIND`) - this is more non-normative but informative: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/#values

Comment: my suggestion is to ask on the Stardog mailing list, the developers are very   kind and helpful

Comment: I also tried the query with binding inside the `SERVICE` clause: `SELECT DISTINCT ?db_uri ?uri ?db_uri_var ?prop ?val {
      
      SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>
{
BIND("http://dbpedia.org/resource/Delta_Air_Lines" as ?uri)
BIND(URI(?uri) as ?db_uri)
?db_uri ?prop ?val .
}
}` - it works as expected with Jena - indeed it doesn't solve your issue when getting variables from outside the query, but there are engines that can optimize and inline rather efficient.

Comment: well, I can see you're already in touch with the Stardog devs on the mailing list

Comment: yes, let's see what the Stardog team comes back with. thx!

Comment: I see this is old but the function for creating an IRI is `IRI()`: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-iri